# Is this question too opinion based?

Tags: discussion

Before I post on RPG and get closed out for being too opinion-based I wanted to ask here on Meta if my question is appropriate.  A friend came up with a character build in 5e that he believes is too over-powered and will disrupt game balance and create too many issues at the table.  From my perspective as a DM, I would have no problem with the character (note that I wouldn't actually be the DM for this character), but he is insistent that it's too powerful.  The question I want to ask is, "Is this *actually* too powerful?" (very opinion based) and/or "will this disrupt the game in a way that will create irreparable harm and skew every combat in favor of this one player, and if so how can a DM mitigate that disruption without creating other issues?"

I'm pretty sure if I post it it will be closed as too opinion based, but I know there can be good subjective answer based on experience to this question.  I also know that without the full context of the question (which I will add when I post the question), it is difficult to tell here if the question is too subjective.  What is the best way to approach these types of borderline opinion-based questions that *may* have great Good Subjective answers?

Comment: Without knowing in what way it is 'too powerful' I would say it is impossible to judge whether the question would be OK. If the power comes from the amount of damage it can do for example, then perhaps an answer that breaks down the numbers and compares them to other builds might suffice

Comment: See: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/what-are-the-standards-for-balance-questions on how to ask balance questions.

Comment: Also: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/22190/140 on the taxonomy of being overpowered.

Answer (score 10):

I hope this answer qualifies as a frame-challenge, because it's not going to actually answer your question:  **Ask it!**

At time of writing, your rep on RPG.SE is nearly 6,000.  You're not a newbie who refuses to learn the format with a history of closed and deleted posts.  You're clearly a contributing member in good standing:  One question that *might* not be a good fit for the site won't hurt you.  If it does turn out to be closed, it happens.  If it's downvoted so severely that you're ashamed to have it on your profile, you can always delete it later, but if it's enough of an edge-case that you're asking this Meta question about it, that's not likely.  On the other hand, it might be well-received and you might get some helpful guidance, either as to why the build is considered overpowered or why it's just fine (and how to explain that case to your friend).

(If you *were* a newbie with a history of closed and deleted posts, however, I'd suggest you not ask it yet, as your account could be just one more bad post away from losing some site functionality.)

Comment: Nice answer; I think it's the only way to find out, realistically.

Comment: Similar answers on these: [Is this overview question ok to ask here?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5416) • [Are these good questions? - What does "Dungeon" mean in "Dungeons and Dragons", and how did that meaning come about?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5733)

Answer (score 5):

> "Is this actually too powerful?" (very opinion based) and/or "will this disrupt the game in a way that will create irreparable harm and skew every combat in favor of this one player, and if so how can a DM mitigate that disruption without creating other issues?"

Are not good questions - they are bad-subjective.

However, a question along the lines of:

> A player has come up with a build that can do X, Y & Z. he is concerned that this will be too powerful because of X, Y & Z.
>
> Is this level of power out of line with other characters of the same level and in what ways?

This is moving it more towards good-subjective.